# Can't use captcha from tomahawk library

Tags: captcha, jsf-1.2, tomahawk

I'm trying to use the captcha component from tomahawk, `<t:captcha>`. Everytime the page loads, the following error appears:

> *com.sun.facelets.tag.TagException: /tiles/competitionSite.xhtml @112,46  Tag Library supports namespace:
>   http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk, but no tag was defined for name:
>   captcha*

I think there's something wrong with the libraries. I checked the tomahawk JARs and `<t:captcha>` should be supported in Tomahawk 1.1.7 or higher. I used multiple versions (e.g. 1.1.13), but `<t:captcha>` never worked. All the other tags like `<t:inputText>` are working fine. I also imported the `batik-awt-util-1.6-1.jar`, because that's necessary for captchas.

Maybe there's a problem with my other libraries? I can't exchange them easily, because there are many dependencies. Here's a list of them:

- `batik-awt-util-1.6-1.jar`
- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-codec-1.3.jar
- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- commons-digester-1.6.jar
- commons-el-1.0.jar
- commons-lang-2.1.jar
- commons-validator-2.1.jar
- el-ri.jar
- jakarta-oro.jar
- jboss-serialization.jar
- jsf-facelets-1.1.12.jar
- jstl-1.1.0.jar
- myfaces-api-1.1.5.jar
- myfaces-impl-1.1.5.jar
- org.springframework.web-3.0.5.jar
- richfaces-api-3.1.6.GA.jar
- richfaces-impl-3.1.6.GA.jar
- richfaces-ui-3.1.6.GA.jar
- `tomahawk-1.1.13.jar`
- urlrewrite-2.6.0.jar

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the mistake. In our CMS the `tomahawk.taglib.xml` file will not be deployed dynamically from the included JAR. I just had to create a new entry like this:

```
  <tag>
    <tag-name>captcha</tag-name>
    <component>
      <component-type>org.apache.myfaces.CAPTCHA</component-type>
      <renderer-type>org.apache.myfaces.CAPTCHA</renderer-type>
    </component>
  </tag>
```

Now I use `<t:captcha>` with tomahawk-1.1.7.jar and batik-awt-util-1.6-1.jar.